# Multi-Domain PDE (Helmholtz Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am studying the acoustics in solid barriers to minimize sound propagation in them.
I was able to solve Helmholtz equation where the barrier is a homogeneous 3D solid plate.

The Question is: I want to solve the Helmholtz equation in a multi-layered plate where every layer is different in terms of several physical characteristics.
I cant find quite a good source to help me do so. Any help please or perhaps directions

PS: I am using MATLAB(TM) to solve the equations numerically.

Comment: Assuming you are working with the simplest form of the equation, all you need is to change the wavenumber for each layer. The toughest part will be the boundaries between each layer. If you have an idea on what the physics would be at those boundaries would help on the implementation (i.e. is there a phase-shift or inversion at the boundary?) Regardless, the quick and dirty approach may be just to string together the PDEs that describes each layer with appropriate boundary conditions in between.

Comment: If plane waves are considered, the approach in @MasterYoda comment is called *Transfer Matrix Method* (TMM). This is explained in the [book](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9780470747339) *Propagation of Sound in Porous Media: Modelling Sound Absorbing Materials* by J.-F. Allard and N. Atalla, where it is applied to multilayered porous media.

Comment: If you want a more precise answer, then you need to set up a more precise question. E.g. the two-layered case with normal incidence, etc.